# Nuxt Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `Nuxt.js` and making an `axios` request however I need to get the request and loop through it twice to get a list and set it back to my data as `products or new products` so I can display it within the view.

However i'm getting the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'newProducts')`.

I can see the correct data in my console log however when I try to set it to `data` I get the error

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            products:[],
            newProducts:[]
        }
    },
    created() { 
        this.fetchData();
    },
    methods:{
        fetchData() {
            this.$axios.get('/products/'+this.$route.name)
            .then((response)=> {
                this.products = response.data
            }).finally(()=>{
                this.formatProducts();
            })
        },
        formatProducts(){
             _.forEach(this.products, function(value){
                _.forEach(value.productList, function(filteredProducts) {
                    console.log(filteredProducts);
                    this.newProducts = filteredProducts;
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Update**

When I use arrow functions for the second each I get an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: values.forEach is not a function`

```
this.products.forEach(function(values){
      values.forEach(products => {
       this.newProducts = products;
       });
 });
```

**Update**

Using two arrow functions I get an `error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')`

```
this.products.forEach((productGroup, index) => {
     this.productGroup.forEach((product, index) => {
     console.log(product);
    });
});
```

Comment: `this` in your second `_.forEach` is referring to the context of the function. If you want the outer scope with your actual array located in `data`, you need to write an arrow function. That way, `this.newProducts` will be referencing what you're expecting. Also, why do you use lodash here? A regular `forEach` is totally fine.

Comment: Updated..I now get TypeError: values.forEach is not a function

Comment: What is inside of values? Can you console log to inspect and see if it has what you expect (an array) there?

Comment: Also, you will also need an arrow function for the first loop. Since it's the same regarding `this`.

Comment: Now I get error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') or if I remove this from this.productGroup I get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Comment: `productGroup.forEach` is enough, no need for `this` in that situation because you're using the local variable.